# Wordpress Page Builder Style Loading Error

Tags: wordpress, loading

I'm having an issue with SiteOrigin's pagebuilder plugin. I have made an entire website using this plugin (therefore I'd prefer to keep using it) but all of a sudden I can no longer add styles (such as backgrounds and pictures behind the widget) to the visual editor widget within rows that I am working on. All I see is just a constant loading screen. This only happens when using the visual editor widget, as on SiteOrigin itself I can edit rows fine, I just can't use the visual editor anymore.

Here's what it's supposed to look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE32A.jpg

Here's what mine looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xk0w.jpg

Depending on the row I am using neither may load.

Here is a list of the plugins I am using:

- Black Studio
- TinyMCE Widget
- Contact Form 7
- Easy Google Fonts
- Lightbox Plus Colorbox
- Page Builder by SiteOrigin
- SiteOrigin Widgets Bundle
- Spacer Title Remover

I have deleted both siteorigin plugins as well as the visual editor plugin on my build and reinstalled them to no avail. Is this a common problem? Does anyone have any idea on how to fix it?

Many Thanks,

JDB

EDIT: Per Omer's advice, I have found the error using Chrome's Javascript Debugger.

```
http://www.website.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?_panelsnonce=3bf1af34d8 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable)

http://www.website.com/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,quicktags,plupload,editor&ver=4.3.1
```

Not sure where to go from here... any ideas?

Thanks

JDB

Comment: Due to the error being a 503, does this mean it is something I've done? Or perhaps something to do with the plugin/host that will be updated in time?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used this plugin before, but it looks like it uses ajax to fetch data, and an error in javascript is avoiding the page to load properly. To check if this is the case, inspect your page with **chrome developer** tools and on the right side look for **javascript errors (console)**. Once you know which file is responsible for the error then you will have to fix that error and everything will start working fine.

Comment: I've found the JavaScript errors, where do I go from here? Is there something going wrong in admin-ajax.php?

Comment: well there isn't anything wrong with the admin-ajax.php itself. But it does tell you that something is wrong path that the ajax is requesting data from. Mostly this kind of errors occur after you change the siteurls/domain/ssl etc. In your edit i can see that the url is not available or somethings wrong going on the server end. I hate to say this but the best option for you would be to  raise a ticket at the plugins support desk https://siteorigin.com/thread/. I just checked quickly and i can see people have lots of issues with the ajax, you might be able to find a fix in the threads.